# How to extract data using json in python

Tags: python

I have an issue with a code I've written. When I run the code I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test23_json_users.py", line 23, in <module>
for user_dict in abc['user_account']['sip_id']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

The code:

```
result = '[{"user_account":[{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1112","sip_id":"23001@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23001","user_id":7973712,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1101","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1113","sip_id":"23002@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23002","user_id":8847075,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1102","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1114","sip_id":"23003@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23003","user_id":3680630,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1103","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1115","sip_id":"23004@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23004","user_id":136391,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1104","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1116","sip_id":"23005@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23005","user_id":5692227,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1105","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1117","sip_id":"23006@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23006","user_id":7559026,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1106","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1118","sip_id":"23007@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23007","user_id":3226075,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1107","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1119","sip_id":"23008@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23008","user_id":6184875,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1108","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1120","sip_id":"23009@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23009","user_id":1711112,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1109","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null},{"address":null,"name":null,"country":null,"password":"****","extension":"1121","sip_id":"23010@50.50.50.201","sip_name":"23010","user_id":5383101,"locked":false,"created":null,"h323_name":"1110","city":null,"email":null,"phone":null,"zip":null}]}'

params = result[result.find('{"'):]
#print params
abc = json.loads(params)

# Here I'm trying to extract just sip_id from the string result using json.
# I am not able to figure out what went wrong .
for user_dict in abc['user_account']['sip_id']:
    print  'usersname : %s' % (user_dict['sip_id'])
```

Comment: when i use regx.. it works fine syntax used  re.findall('(?<=\\"sip_id\\":\\")[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+(?=\\")',result)

Comment: Pro tip: use `from pprint import pprint`, then `pprint(abc)` to get a much better feel of what your data structure looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abc['user_account']` is supposed to be a list.

A list `a=['hello',1,2,'people']` has 4 elements accessed by indexes `a[0]` through `a[3]`.

A dictionary `d={'a':1,'b':2}` has keys and values. In this case `d['a']` has value 1, `d[b']` has 2.

If you want to access something in `abc['user_account']`, type `abc['user_account'][42]`. If you want to iterate over it

```
for a in abc['user_account']:
  print a
```

Comment: Cool Works fine now . I tried this :     for user_dict in abc['user_account']:

        print  'usersname : %s' % (user_dict['sip_id'])

Comment: Is there no way i can extract out just the sip id with one single line of  code :                                                                                 for user_dict in abc['user_account']['sip_id']: print 'usersname : %s' % (user_dict['sip_id'])

Comment: If one answer solves your problem, please **accept** the correct answer by clicking the check mark. Do leave comments if you need more clarifications.

Comment: `for a in abc['user_account']:
...   print a['sip_id']` sorry for posting in single line

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for user_dict in abc['user_account']['sip_id']:
```

to

```
for user_dict in abc['user_account']:
```